# Specific Reports

Tags: contributions, reports

I'm having trouble running a report and I hope someone can help.

I would like to run a report that shows me the name and address of the contributors between now and 2011. I have a database that goes back to 2005.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it will help others help you if you flesh out your question with some clarifications about what you have already tried and why they don't deliver the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you need a list of all the contact who has made a contribution since 2005 without any duplicate contact

you can get a list of all the members since 2005 to till date as below

Report using Civicrm 4.7.12

Reports -> contribution Reports -> Contribution Summary

In cloumns: select contact name and address fields as you needed

In Grouping: just select contact ID so you will not get repeated records

In Filters: just select the date range

then refresh the report and you will get all the records you wanted

I guess this helps!!!

Comment: This was a great solution. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!